# How do you trace a request which is pushed from server in FireBug

Tags: firebug, signalr

I am using SignalR library to push notification from server to client. When notification is pushed from server there is no trace in firebug. How can i trace this request ?

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe FireBug offers a way to see individual messages over Web Sockets yet, therefore you will not see any trace of messages at that level. IE 10 Dev Tools also do not support seeing Web Socket communications either. Chrome Dev Tools added support for seeing individual Web Socket messages early in 2012 IIRC.

What you can do to get some visibility into what SignalR itself is doing is set logging = true on the hub like so:

```
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
```

This will cause SignalR to spew trace information to the debugger console. You can do this "on the fly" at run time or at load time in your page when you actually set up the connection.

Finally, if you're familiar with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/), you can always stick that in the middle of any of the browsers to view Web Socket communications.

**UPDATE:**

Thought of something else if, for some reason, Fiddler is not a viable option for you. You can always force the transport to be `longPolling` while you're debugging so that you avoid Web Sockets and just use plain HTTP which can (obviously) be seen in FireBug.